# Runtime Segmentation fault in fortran

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran

First of all, sorry for the Spanish annotations.

```
program gauss
implicit none

integer, parameter :: d=30
real*8, dimension(d, d+1) :: a
real*8, dimension(d) :: b, x
integer :: k, i, n
integer, dimension(d) :: pvt
real*8 :: eps = 0.0000001

!Lectura matriz
character (len=32) :: nombre
print*, 'Dame el nombre del fichero de datos'
read*, nombre
open (unit=1, file=nombre, status='OLD')
read(1,*) n
do i=1, n
    read(1,*) a(i,1:n)
end do
read(1,*) b(1:n)
close(unit=1)
a(1:n,n+1) = b(1:n)

!Eliminación gaussiana
do k=1,n-1

    !Búsqueda del pivote
    pvt(k:k) = maxloc(abs(a(k:n,k))) + k-1
    if (abs(a(pvt(k),k)) <= eps) stop 'matriz singular'

    !Intercambio de filas
    if(pvt(k) /= k) then
        a(n+1,1:n+1) = a(pvt(k),1:n+1)
        a(pvt(k),1:n+1) = a(k,1:n+1)
        a(k,1:n+1) = a(n+1,1:n+1)
    end if

    do i=k+1,n
        a(i,k) = a(i,k)/a(k,k)
        a(i,k+1:n+1) = a(i,k+1:n+1) - a(i,k)*a(k,k+1:n+1)
    end do
end do

!a(n,n) == 0?
if (abs(a(n,n)) <= eps) stop 'matriz singular'

!Sustitución regresiva
do i=n,1,-1
    x(i) = (a(i,n+1) - dot_product(a(i,i+1:n),x(i+1:n)))/a(i,i)
end do

print*, 'Solucion:'
print*, x(1:n)

end program gauss
```

I have written this program for a simple lab practice at my degree and it worked just fine when I ran it there. However, I just installed the mingw compiler back home and when I run the program and input the file name, I get the following error:

```
Porgram received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0 ffffffffffffffff
#1 ffffffffffffffff
#2 ffffffffffffffff
#3 ffffffffffffffff
#4 ffffffffffffffff
#5 ffffffffffffffff
#6 ffffffffffffffff
#7 ffffffffffffffff
#8 ffffffffffffffff
#9 ffffffffffffffff
#10 ffffffffffffffff
#11 ffffffffffffffff
#12 ffffffffffffffff
#13 ffffffffffffffff
#14 ffffffffffffffff
#15 ffffffffffffffff
#16 ffffffffffffffff
#17 ffffffffffffffff
#18 ffffffffffffffff
#19 ffffffffffffffff
```

The file I'm using as input is just

```
5
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
1 2 3 4 5
```

I don't know what may be possibly happening because as I said this same code and matrix worked just fine when I did it in another computer.

Comment: Can you try compiling with the flags `-O0 -g` and then see if the error output is more helpful?

Comment: I did what you said and nothing appeared during the compilation. Once I ran the program I encountered the same error.

Comment: The same with exactly `ffffffffffffffff`? Try `-Wall -fcheck=all`.

Comment: The same again: [link](https://gyazo.com/bf2640d04fe6c0f426e465b0fe79727f)

Comment: Please note that `real*8` is not valid Fortran and was never part of any ISO Fortran standard. Instead, either use named constants from `ISO_Fortran_env` or `selected_real_kind` to improve portability. Lastly, use the `newunit` specifier to open your file instead of hard-coding file identification units.

Comment: You forgot `-g` in that link. Are you sure it is `ffffffffffffffff` with `-g`?

Comment: @jlokimlin I am known to be very annoying and nitpicking, but in this case I think it is not worth it. There are so many codes using the `*4` which is quite portable (better than `real(4)` imho) and there may be good reason to not use stuff from Fortran 2008.

Comment: @Edelopo Does your compiler produce any other working programs?

Comment: I notice that you use `unit=1` for your data read. Please select a different number, at least 10. I don't know for `gfortran` on Windows, but these units are often reserved for stdin/stdout/errout. I can't reproduce your error with gfortran v5.4 on Linux.